# Discrete Definition of a Limit

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My professor defines a limit the following way:

> Let $f: \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a sequence and $L\in\mathbb R$. $f$ converges to $L$ if $$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R^+ \exists N\in\mathbb N\forall n\in \mathbb N(n>N \rightarrow |f_n-L|<\epsilon)$$

Which is the dramatic way of saying $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n=L$$

Can someone help me unpack this definition and how I can apply it like one applies the typical epsilon-delta definition of a limit?

Comment: Off hand idea - use $\frac{1}{n}$ to serve as the variable instead of $n$.

Comment: "Can someone help me unpack this definition" : somewhat off topic - are you sure that this is a good idea?  The professor's definition of convergence of a sequence is **standard**.  Personally, I would advise becoming just as comfortable with this definition with respect to sequences as you are the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition, with respect to functions.

Comment: @user2661923 That's the goal. By unpack I mean break down to simplify the definition

Comment: In that case, I question your approach.  I advise the alternative approach of stretching your intuition as follows: (1) Try to construct a sequence that does **not** converge to a limit but that **does** satisfy the professor's definition. (2) Vice-versa - try to construct a sequence that you *regard* as convergent but that does **not** satisfy the professor's definition.  With each of these two tasks, confront the issues and stretch your intuition around why each of these two tasks is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, $f(n)=\frac 1n$ converges to zero.

This means that given any $\epsilon>0$, eventually $f(n)$ will always be within $\epsilon$ distance away from $0$. By "eventually", we mean for all $n$ bigger than some $N$. Here's a picture illustrating what it means for $a_n\to a$.

[image]

This is what your definition is saying. Indeed, by the Archimedean property, given any $\epsilon>0$, we can find an $N_\epsilon$ big enough such that $\frac 1{N_\epsilon}<\epsilon$. For all $n$ bigger than this $N_\epsilon$, we get that
$$\Big|\frac1n - 0\Big| = \frac1n \leqslant \frac{1}{N_\epsilon} < \epsilon,$$
and this proves that $\frac1n\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

This *is* the "epsilon-delta" style defniition for limits at infinity; the only difference being that the bound variable (i.e. $n$) ranges over the natural numbers instead of over the real numbers. It is, other than that one change, the same definition as for the value of

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$$

for $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow D$, $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, and so $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Intuitively, the terms involved have the same meaning: $\epsilon$ is the tolerance, and $N$ is the lower bound on the input on $f$ needed to approximate $L$ within that desired tolerance.

Insofar as how you use it, you should use it in the same way that you use the other. If you want to prove that, say,

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$$

you should ask yourself: "if I want to approximate $0$ to within $\epsilon$ - say, +/-0.001 - by plugging something in for $n$, how big must I make that $n$ to cause that to happen?" And you can easily see that if $N = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, that that will provide the necessary tolerance, because if

$$n > \frac{1}{\epsilon} > 0$$

then

$$0 < \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$$

by virtue of the elementary fact that if

$$x > y$$

then

$$\frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{y}$$

for positive reals $x$ and $y$, and also that $\frac{1}{x}$ has the same sign as $x$ for any real $x \ne 0$.